# Convert /tf to nav_msgs/Odometry

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-msgs, robot-pose-ekf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use robot_pose_ekf to receive data from a IMU and a visual odometry source. This last one only publishes a /tf between to frames and I want to get the geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance from it.

Is there a proper way of converting a /tf to a nav_msgs/Odometry message?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:
Thanks all for the answers! I'm going to take a comment in a single answer. I'm using a Asus Xtion Pro Live with rgbdslam_v2 package. This last one publishes /tf between a fixed_frame and a choosen frame from us at a 10hz rate. I need this to be an odom type of message to insert it in robot_pose_ekf.

I don't really know if I'm using the right package for the purpose, but I lost a serious amount of time porting it to an ARM platform (an Odroid) and I didn't want to abandoned this one just because it doesn't give me odometry out-of-the-box. Besides, changing to, for example, to ccny-rgbd-tools will probably mean a great amount of work again to get it ported to ARM.

So can anyone point me out how can I get a proper convertion from tf to Odometry. I'm not really a hardcoder so point out some parts of code in the ccny_rgbd_tools visual_odometry.cpp would be good.

Thanks again!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185548/convert-/tf-to-nav_msgs/odometry/) by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-08**:
The answer which was written by me gives the sample code from ccny_rgbd_tools's visual_odometry.cpp

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-08**:
In this case, follow the sample code. You probably want to set the covariance to something hard coded, when you put it into the EKF.

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-07-09**:
@dornhege can you please point me some code sample to hard code a good covariance matrix? I'm following the dirty fix in: http://answers.ros.org/question/66489/combine-visual-odometry-data-from-ccny_rgbd-with-encodersimu/
But it doesn't seem to be good in my case (since I will have 6DOF motion).
Tkx

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-09**:
I'm not sure how you want to do more than a simple hack if you don't have the data.

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-07-09**:
Maybe a normal distribution for each matrix value?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-09**:
That's what this hack gives you.

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-07-09**:
0.2 , 0.2 , 999999 , 999999 , 999999 , 0.2 doesn't seem Gaussian but ok. Anyway, giving that I need a 6DOF motion, give a 0.2 instead of 999999 to other values seams reasonable right?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-09**:
Those are variances under the assumption that a diagonal matrix is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at poseTFToMsg

http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a4a85fbf875a029e296806075b862d321

http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html

Sample code block from here
https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/blob/master/ccny_rgbd/src/apps/visual_odometry.cpp#L360

This code below converts a TF msg to a odometry msg, you can find example for pose msg also in the link above

```
             void VisualOdometry::publishOdom(const std_msgs::Header& header)
          {
                OdomMsg odom;
                odom.header.stamp = header.stamp;
                odom.header.frame_id = fixed_frame_;
                 tf::poseTFToMsg(f2b_, odom.pose.pose);
                  odom_publisher_.publish(odom);
          }
```

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-07-08**:
I will check this. Probably have to adapt graph_manager.cpp in rgbdslam src folder to get this kind of message. Thanks!

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-08**:
I do not think there is need to look at graph_manager.cpp. In the above visual_odometry.cpp, you can find another function called 'publishTf' that actually converts the estimated transformation to a TF and also to odom msg, pose msg etc. I think completely going through the visual_odometry.cpp and its header file where `f2b_` is defined should help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Proper way: No

Why: Odometry contains Twist and Covariances. Both are not present in /tf. You could derivate tf information to get Twists and maybe somehow give covariances, but I wouldn't consider that proper.
Ideally ones goes the other way and produces /tf from Odometry.

Depending on what you want to do with the data, Just putting pose information into the odometry might be sufficient for the application that needs an Odometry message.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

nav_msgs/Odometry contains translation, orientation as well as twist (linear and angular velocities)

tf on the other hand only contains translation and orientation

So unless you can find a way to derive the twist...

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1